# If I was to poke two holes in a water filled balloon would it lose water twice as fast a a balloon with one hole?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow

if I was to assume that the only force behind water coming out of the holes is the pressure i.e., the height of the water remaining which is constantly changing (declining) as water leaves the balloon, so the speed at which water leaves is highest at the beginning and slows down gradually. therefore I'm assuming the rate at which water leaves the balloon as a function of time is of a degree>1? (can't determine weather it's squared or cubic).

now intuitively it makes sense,at least to me, to say that a balloon with two holes would lose water twice as fast but I also know that the rate at which it loses the pressure is faster as well, so wouldn't it at some time reach a point where the water coming out of the one holed balloon > than any holes of the two holed one? and maybe both would deflate at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

The flow rate is dependent on the pressure, and the pressure is dependent on the height of water above the hole.

Over a short enough period of time, the change in water level can be ignored and the flow rate can be considered constant. At an infinitesimally short scale we get the concept of instantaneous flow, which again can be applied over a short time scale to closely approximate the change in water volume during that time.

Let's say your water level starts at 100mm and your needle pokes a hole that at that pressure loses 1mm/s of water. (I'm phrasing the measurements as such so that we can work with pressure instead of volume.) You poke one hole in the bottom of balloon A and at the same time poke two holes in the bottom of balloon B. Over the first second, the water level in A drops by 1mm and the water level in B drops by 2mm, a difference of 1mm.

Since the pressure is decreasing proportionally to the water height, the flow rate in the next second is reduced. Between t=1 and t=2, balloon A loses .99mm and balloon B loses .98mm, so the total water level difference is 2.98mm-1.99mm = 0.99mm. Continuing such numerical analysis considering only pressure implies that the two balloons asymptotically approach zero flow as the empty and thus empty out at the same time - an infinite time in the future.

Obviously the infinity there indicates that we've left something out, and that missing factor is the consideration of what causes the pressure in the first place. In the typical case of a rigid container, it's gravity: and even when the water level approaches zero height, the flow rate is non-zero due to the actual weight of the water. When the water level is higher pressure dominates flow rate, but the water weight has its own effect throughout the process. So rather than asymptotically stopping, the flow continues at least above a minimum rate.

The end result considering both pressure and gravity (or tension in a balloon, or a pump) is that the balloon with more holes empties quicker, because the flow rate for a given water level is higher with more drain holes and the balloon with more holes reaches each successive level sooner. The balloon with fewer holes falls behind and never catches up.

Comment: *The flow rate is dependent on the pressure, and the pressure is dependent on the height of water above the hole* does the elasticity of the balloon material have any (significant) effect on the pressure?

Comment: Yes, it does. I admit my answer is actually more geared toward a rigid container emptying due to gravity, but the concepts are the same. At any rate, the tension in the balloon reduces as the water volume decreases, which is the original problem my answer does address as to why the two containers don't empty at the same time.

Comment: Considering the case this way assumes that the water is actually flowing from the holes, while if one has watched videos of balloon being poked, that were filmed with high speed cameras, it is more like the rubber that was once stretched now collapses around the water, leaving the water to drop due to gravity.